# HTML/CSS/Ruby on Rails Header with logo that overhangs into page content

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to be able to have a logo overhang from a header, see [this link](http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/wordpress/themes/studiopress-genesis-theme-framework/how-to-overhang-a-wordpress-header-image-in-genesis-5268/) for a visual example. From what I've searched, most of the results are about making this happen with WordPress rather than just in terms of HTML/CSS (including the provided link). I'm using RoR alongside Twitter Bootstrap in order to create some quick styling of the page including the header (possibly pertinent information).

I'm guessing the answer to this question really is HTML/CSS-centric, so, if I had a header `<div>` that included a logo to the left as well as a set of navigation links to the right, how could I go about making that logo overhang into the rest of the page below?

Also, bonus points if the ability to add a slight shadow to the part that overhangs is included :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the z-index property (CSS) to set your logo image so that it is always in front, then you can position the image in your header and it will look like it's hanging. The slight shadow should be part of the image itself.

Comment: Does setting the z-index property ensure that the size of the image will not influence the size of it's containing (header) `<div>`? When I simply added an image tag within the header `<div>`, it increased the height of the header to include the image.

Comment: @MandM You can float the image to remove it from the div so that the height of the header will not change. Try it out and let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css code with

```
position: absolute;
```

This will ensure your logo floats on top of wherever you want it. Then adjust how you want to place your logo image with:

```
margin-top: 100px;
```

using whatever px you want.